# How many concurrent PHP Processes can I run?

Tags: php, multiprocessing

I am successfully starting and running concurrent PHP-Processes with:

```
$WshShell = new COM('WScript.Shell');
foreach(array('foo', 'bar', ...) as $i) {
    $oExec = $WshShell->Run('C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php' . phpversion() . '\\php.exe ' .
        '-c C:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\Apache2.2.21\\bin ' . // Use correct php.ini!
        '-f C:\\Users\\Max\\Project\\start.php "' . $i . '" ' . 0, false);
    }
}
```

I am wondering how many PHP-Processes I can run at the same Time (in a usual Windows and Linux Environment)?

Comment: I'd assume as many as can fit in your RAM.

Comment: You might want to investigate [php5-fpm](http://php-fpm.org/).

Comment: Relevant: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/07/08/3261309.aspx